# How can I hard link a folder to a different place per-user?

Tags: windows, redirection

I have a particular piece of software which likes to store files in a subdirectory of its install folder. I believe that if this software were installed in, say, C:\Program Files, that folder virtualization would take over and the files would end up in the per-user VirtualStore directory. In my case, however, this application is installed elsewhere.

I could set up a login script to set up a hard link with mklink upon login, but that would have issues with multiple users logged in simultaneously, and seems like a headache to begin with.

Is there a way to do something similar to folder virtualization in the general, non-programfiles case?

Comment: I would be shocked if that was possible without either hooking or a file system filter driver. I may be proved wrong, though.

Comment: What is the name of the software?

Comment: In this case, Kerbal Space Program. It's a general problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Many programs will use an environment variable to place the files.  This is normally how the files end up in the users directory structure.  There are standard variables that can be used to determine the appropriate directory tree.

Some programs write files relative to where they startup.  The default location is usually the directory where the program is found.  Try changing the directory the program starts in by editing the properties of the icon.  If this works use one of variables that point the user's directory to generate the directory the program starts in.

The program may have a command line or configuration option that can override the directory being used. You can modify the properties of the application to change its command line options.

If none of these options work, I think you are out of luck.  Try to find a well-behaved program that does store it's files in the users directory.